# Will a captured __weak variable be copied to heap with the _block_copy() function?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

When a Block which captures a `__strong` variable is copied to the heap,  the variable is also copied to the heap with the `_block_copy()` function.

But what would happen when using a `__weak` variable?

```
id __weak weakObj = someObj;
someBlock = [^() {
   //using __weak variable
} copy];
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have tried this:

```
NSNumber *testNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:5];

NSNumber *__weak weakObj = testNumber;
NSLog(@"original weakObj address = %p",&weakObj);

id someBlock = [^() {
    NSLog(@"value in block:%ld",(long)weakObj.integerValue);
    NSLog(@"weakObj address inside block = %p",&weakObj);
} copy];

testNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:6];
NSLog(@"value outside:%ld",(long)testNumber.integerValue);

[someBlock invoke];

NSLog(@"weakObj address = %p",&weakObj);
```

Result is:

```
original weakObj address = 0x7fff5fbff750
value outside:6
value in block:5
weakObj address inside block = 0x1005023f0
weakObj address = 0x7fff5fbff750
```

**Conclusion:**

1. Inside the block, the weak object's memory address is changed. So, weak object is copied to heap. And __block_copy() function may be used.
2. Outside the block,the weak object keeps the original memory address after copying.

Answer (score 0):

When a block captures any non-`__block` variable, the variable is always copied into an independent copy kept with the block *when the block is created*, not when the block is copied. It is true even if the block is *not* moved to the heap. This is also true regardless of the type of the variable (whether it is a primitive type, or ARC-managed strong or weak pointer type).

For example, if you run the following example with ARC turned off:

```
int foo = 5;
void (^someBlock)(void) = ^{
  NSLog(@"value in block: %d", foo);
};
foo = 6;
NSLog(@"value outside block: %d", foo); // logs "value outside block: 6"
someBlock();                            // logs "value in block: 5"
NSLog(@"block is: %@", someBlock);      // logs "block is: <__NSStackBlock__: 0x7fff523f0ba0>"
```

You will notice that the block was never moved to the heap, as it was a `__NSStackBlock__` at the end (I did it with ARC turned off to have control over the copying of blocks because ARC might implicitly move blocks to the heap defensively). You will also notice that the value of the variable inside the block was not affected by an assignment to the variable outside the block after the block was created, proving that the variable was copied before the assignment (i.e. when the block was created). This demonstration was done with a primitive `int` to show that it works for any type -- it doesn't only apply to ARC-managed pointer types -- but it is still equally true for ARC-managed pointer types, both strong and weak.